# Read JS variable in C# / Forwarding JS variable to visual studio performance test?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, visual-studio-2010, performance

People here are using visual studio for performance testing. Now there are some small issues with some javascript parts: they are not able to check the performance of the javascript part with visual studio web-performance testing.

I never used visual studio performance test, so I really have no idea how to bench stuff there, but I saw there are a lot of solutions for web + js performance check. I thought we could use other tools and frameworks, but its not allowed. People here want to use visual studio for everything. So this is making stuff more tricky.

If I would have to check the javascript performance, I would easily do something like this:

```
var begin = new Date();
functionA();
functionB();
functionX();
var end = new Date();
var bench = end - begin;
```

At the end I can see in the variable `bench` my result. Now I just have to pass this variable "somehow" to the visual studio performance test? Via C#? Or how is this stuff working? Could this be a good solution? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because VS Performance Test Engine doesn't run any client-side code at all, it works on HTTP level only. So the code you provided as an example would never be run.

Take a look here for the proof - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520100.aspx

> Because the Web Performance Test Engine works at the HTTP layer, it
>   does not run client-side scripting like JavaScript or ActiveX
>   controls. Web Performance Tests are concerned with generating load on
>   a server.. Therefore,, client-side scripting that only affects the
>   appearance of a Web page is not significant to the Web Performance
>   Test. Client-side scripting that sets parameter values or results in
>   additional HTTP requests, such as AJAX, does affect the load on the
>   server and might require you to manually modify the Web Performance
>   Test to simulate the scripting.
>
> A common misconception is that because recording occurs in Internet
>   Explorer, and the Web Performance Test Result Viewer displays results
>   in a browser control, Web performance tests must somehow execute using
>   Internet Explorer. This is not the case. All requests are executed
>   directly using the Web Performance Test Engine; no interaction with
>   Internet Explorer or any other browser occurs. The Web Performance
>   Test Engine communicates directly with the target Web server using
>   standard HTTP request/response messages.

So the only way would be to use other solutions to check javascript performance, or implement your own, based on Selenium for example. I think it's possible to automate such measurements using Selenium RC which can be run from Visual Studio as a part of a build  (if your requirement is to use Visual Studio for everything).

Answer (score 2):

Sure this can work, but I'm not sure if it can directly bridge with VS performance test. An alternative could just be creating your own if you are dying to integrate with C# and VS.

In that case the question would lead to how to  bridge JS and C#.  This can be done with the .NET platform if you embed your JS on a page and then run it with a WebBrowser control.  In your javascript, you can pass information back to a C# application by referencing `window.external`. Here is an example in your javascript:

```
window.external.performanceCallback([yourdata]);
```

to call a performanceCallback() method in the class that is housing your WebBrowser control.  However, before you can do so, you have to make your class visible to the page that your webbrowser is opening (window.external being the instanced class that you're referencing).

So, to set window.external, when you're creating webBrowser in C#:

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

In addition, you have to mark the class with the ComVisible attribute

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

As a reminder, the WebBrowserControl **depends on the version on IE** that you have installed on your computer. So be careful on versioning, javascript will only perform to the extent of what his/her version of IE can handle. Make sure your JS runs on all reasonable versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can't monitor JavaScript directly, but you can get the JavaScript to call a C# web service with timing details periodically.  (Granted, this adds extra overhead, which will definitely skew the results, and may negate the entire purpose.  If you're doing this test on a LAN, the latency should be somewhat mitigated.)

JavaScript

```
var log = function (message) {
    $.ajax('/path/to/log', {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({message:message})
    });
}
// then just call it like so in appropriate places: log('started foo at 12:34:56');
```

C#:

asmx service or MVC controller or anything that accepts an ajax post

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520100.aspx